# NaN в таймере в Safari

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, таймер

```js
var YearS = 2020;
var MonthS = 03;
var DayS = 20;
var HourS = 12;
var MinS = 00;

function updatecountdown() {
  var now = new Date();
  timeN = (now.getMinutes()) + now.getHours() + now.getDate() + now.getMonth() + now.getFullYear();
  time = (MinS - 1) + HourS + DayS + MonthS + YearS;
  if (time == timeN) {
    window.location.reload();
  }
  setTimeout(updatecountdown, 1000);
}
updatecountdown();

function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = "20 03 2020 12:00:00";
initializeClock('countdown', deadline);
```

```html
<div id="countdown" class="countdown">
  <div class="countdown-number">
    <span class="days countdown-time"></span>
    <span class="countdown-text">ДНЕЙ</span>
  </div>
  <div class="countdown-number">
    <span class="hours countdown-time"></span>
    <span class="countdown-text">ЧАСОВ</span>
  </div>
  <div class="countdown-number">
    <span class="minutes countdown-time"></span>
    <span class="countdown-text">МИНУТ</span>
  </div>
  <div class="countdown-number">
    <span class="seconds countdown-time"></span>
    <span class="countdown-text">СЕКУНД</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Возникла проблема. Создал JS таймер. Во всех браузерах корректно работает, а Safari вместо цифр пишет NaN. В консоли ошибок нет.
Прикладываю код таймера

Comment: Создайте работающий пример - кнопка "Фрагмент кода" в редакторе вопроса.

Comment: @Igor Вроде сделал

Comment: у меня chrome 80, винда 10, тоже NaN

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю, как в Сафари учитываются/передаются установки локализации. Сто против одного, что не парсится дата `"20 03 2020 12:00:00";`. Используйте

```
var deadline = new Date(2020, 3, 20, 12, 0, 0);
```

Имейте в виду, что месяц `3` - в данном случае апрель.

---

У меня в Chrome тоже NaN - северо-американская локализация - месяц перед числом.

Comment: Почему апрель? И не испортится ли из-за этого работа скрипта?

Comment: @Дмитрий https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Comment: @Дмитрий Испортится - почините. Ваш же скрипт.

Comment: Нет, такое решение не помогло

Comment: @Дмитрий Такое решение помогло. Вы его к себе неаккуратно скопировали.

Comment: Можете помочь сделать это аккуратно, пожалуйста? Буду очень признателен

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в дате, которую вы передаете. Такой формат не удается распарсить. 100% рабочий формат, который почти всегда парсится - `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` - `2020-03-20 12:00:00`.
Так же, если нет надобности, можно убрать время, оставив только дату - `2020-03-20` - будет так же успешно работать.

```js
var YearS = 2020;
var MonthS = 03;
var DayS = 20;
var HourS = 12;
var MinS = 00;

function updatecountdown() {
  var now = new Date();
  timeN = (now.getMinutes()) + now.getHours() + now.getDate() + now.getMonth() + now.getFullYear();
  time = (MinS - 1) + HourS + DayS + MonthS + YearS;
  if (time == timeN) {
    window.location.reload();
  }
  setTimeout(updatecountdown, 1000);
}
updatecountdown();

function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = "2020-03-20 12:00:00";
initializeClock('countdown', deadline);
```

```html
<div id="countdown" class="countdown">
  <div class="countdown-number">
    <span class="days countdown-time"></span>
    <span class="countdown-text">ДНЕЙ</span>
  </div>
  <div class="countdown-number">
    <span class="hours countdown-time"></span>
    <span class="countdown-text">ЧАСОВ</span>
  </div>
  <div class="countdown-number">
    <span class="minutes countdown-time"></span>
    <span class="countdown-text">МИНУТ</span>
  </div>
  <div class="countdown-number">
    <span class="seconds countdown-time"></span>
    <span class="countdown-text">СЕКУНД</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможно я не вижу, но Вы как-то редактировали мой код или переслали его?

Comment: @Дмитрий, `var deadline = "2020-03-20 12:00:00";`. Так просто)

Comment: Код работает корректно, но в Safari проблема осталась

Comment: @Дмитрий, Не имею Safari под рукой (и не под рукой тоже), но попробуйте еще заменить Date.parse на new Date(endtime). Чтоб получилось `var t = new Date(endtime) - new Date();`

Comment: Ничего не изменилось. Как и в прошлый раз