# Почему код не работает на iPhone?

Tags: javascript

Нужна помощь. Подскажите почему данный таймер не работает на iPhone. На ПК и на андройде все ок, а на iPhone выводит NuN.

Вот ссылка тут можно [чекнуть](https://olegmukom.ru/sites/flint2/)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

var dateEnd = '04.30.2020';              // Устанавливаем дату окончания таймера в формате мм.дд.гггг

var countdown = document.getElementById("tiles");

getCountdown();

setInterval(function () { getCountdown(); }, 1000);

function getCountdown(){
    var today = Number(new Date().getTime());        

    dateEnd = Number(new Date(dateEnd).getTime());

    var dateDef = Number(+dateEnd - +today);

    var day1 = Number(+dateDef / 86400000);
    var dayDay = Math.floor(+day1);
    if(dayDay <= 0){
        dayDay = 0
    }

    var hours1 = Number((+dateDef - (+dayDay * 86400000)) / 3600000);
    var hoursHour = Math.floor(+hours1);
    if(hoursHour <= 0){
        hoursHour = 0
    }

    var minutes1 = Number((+dateDef - ((+hoursHour * 3600000) + (+dayDay * 86400000))) / 60000);
    var minutesMinute = Math.floor(+minutes1);
    if(minutesMinute <= 0){
        minutesMinute = 0
    }

    countdown.innerHTML = "<span>" + dayDay + "</span><span>" + hoursHour + "</span><span>" + minutesMinute + "</span>"; 
}

});
```

html и стили я думаю можно не показывать, там просто див куда я вывожу значения.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1079731

Comment: Спасибо, Проблема в формате даты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот правильный формат даты если у кого-то будут такие же проблемы и вдруг наткнутся на мой вопрос yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss